# Select and Remove Characters

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to remove remove the string that the user enter and the next 16 characters after this string... When I'm removing just the string that I enter, it's working, but when I ask to remove the others next 16 characters it's stop to work. Could some one help me?

The file is:

04_03(+16 characters) text 04_03(+16characters)

04_03(+16 characters) text 04_03(+16characters) text 04_03(+16characters)

text 04_03(+16characters)

The user enters:
strSearch = 04_03

I would like to delete the string 04_03 more the next 16 characters after this string, independetly which characters they are from the file.

The final file should be:

text

text text

text

```
Global strSearch As String
Global strLenght As Double

Function RegExpReplace(ByVal WhichString As String, _
                    ByVal pattern As String, _
                    ByVal ReplaceWith As String, _
                    Optional ByVal IsGlobal As Boolean = True, _
                    Optional ByVal IsCaseSensitive As Boolean = True) As String
'Declaring the object
Dim objRegExp As Object

'Initializing an Instance
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

'Setting the Properties
objRegExp.Global = IsGlobal
objRegExp.pattern = pattern
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = Not IsCaseSensitive

'Execute the Replace Method
RegExpReplace = objRegExp.Replace(WhichString, ReplaceWith)

End Function

Sub findCharacter()

strSearch = InputBox("How starts the text that you would like to remove?", "Character's Search")
If strSearch = "" Then Exit Sub

End Sub

Sub RemoveCharacters()

Dim pattern As String
Dim str As String
Dim u As String

With Sheets("Sheet1")
.Select

Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    For Lrow = 1 To Lastrow Step 1

        str = Cells(Lrow, 1).Value
        pattern = strSearch + " [\w \W \s] {16}"
        Cells(Lrow, 1).Value = RegExpReplace(str, pattern, "")

    Next Lrow

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need RegEx for this? You can achieve what you want using Simple Excel formulas or if you still want to use VBA then perhaps a MID and REPLACE?

Comment: I don't need RegEx, in one line could have 2 string that I want to delete, and it is not necessary the same what I have after what the user gave to me!

Comment: The command Find look just for the first string in the line right?

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: And what if say there are only 8 characters after `04_03` and not 16?

Comment: Than you shoulnd't delete...

Comment: ok posting an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, pos As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim strToRepl As String, strSearch As String

    strSearch = InputBox("How does the text start that you would like to remove?", "Character's Search")
    If strSearch = "" Then Exit Sub

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            pos = InStr(1, .Range("A" & i).Value, strSearch, vbTextCompare)

            If pos > 0 Then
                n = Len(.Range("A" & i).Value) - pos

                If Not Len(strSearch) + 16 > n Then
                    strToRepl = Mid(.Range("A" & i).Value, pos, Len(strSearch) + 16)
                    .Range("A" & i).Value = Replace(.Range("A" & i).Value, strToRepl, "")
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Yes! =) Thanks.. Now it's look really simple! ;)